# How to evenly distribute data in apache pig output files?

Tags: apache-pig

I've got a pig-latin script that takes in some xml, uses the XPath UDF to pull out some fields and then stores the resulting fields:

```
REGISTER udf-lib-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;
DEFINE XPath com.blah.udfs.XPath();

docs = LOAD '$input' USING com.blah.storage.XMLLoader('root') as (content:chararray);

results = FOREACH docs GENERATE XPath(content, 'root/id'), XPath(content, 'root/otherField'), content;

store results into '$output';
```

Note that we're using pig-0.12.0 on our cluster, so I ripped the XPath/XMLLoader classes out of pig-0.14.0 and put them in my own jar so that I could use them in 0.12.

This above script works fine and produces the data that I'm looking for. However, it generates over 1,900 partfiles with only a few mbs in each file. I learned about the default_parallel option, so I set that to 128 to try and get 128 partfiles. I ended up having to add a piece to force a reduce phase to achieve this. My script now looks like:

```
set default_parallel 128;
REGISTER udf-lib-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;
DEFINE XPath com.blah.udfs.XPath();

docs = LOAD '$input' USING com.blah.storage.XMLLoader('root') as (content:chararray);

results = FOREACH docs GENERATE XPath(content, 'root/id'), XPath(content, 'root/otherField'), content;

forced_reduce = FOREACH (GROUP results BY RANDOM()) GENERATE FLATTEN(results);
store forced_reduce into '$output';
```

Again, this produces the expected data. Also, I now get 128 part-files. My problem now is that the data is not evenly distributed among the part-files. Some have 8 gigs, others have 100 mb. I should have expected this when grouping them by RANDOM() :).

My question is what would be the preferred way to limit the number of part-files yet still have them evenly-sized? I'm new to pig/pig latin and assume I'm going about this in the completely wrong way.

p.s. the reason I care about the number of part-files is because I'd like to process the output with spark and our spark cluster seems to do a lot better with a smaller number of files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still looking for a way to do this directly from the pig script but for now my "solution" is to repartition the data within the spark process that works on the output of the pig script. I use the `RDD.coalesce` function to rebalance the data.

Answer (score 0):

From the first code snippet, I am assuming it is map only job since you are not using any aggregates.

Instead of using reducers, set the property pig.maxCombinedSplitSize

```
    REGISTER udf-lib-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;
    DEFINE XPath com.blah.udfs.XPath();

    docs = LOAD '$input' USING com.blah.storage.XMLLoader('root') as (content:chararray);

    results = FOREACH docs GENERATE XPath(content, 'root/id'), XPath(content, 'root/otherField'), content;

    store results into '$output';        
exec;
        set pig.maxCombinedSplitSize 1000000000; -- 1 GB(given size in bytes)
        x = load '$output' using PigStorage();
        store x into '$output2' using PigStorage();
```

pig.maxCombinedSplitSize - setting this property will make sure each mapper reads around 1 GB data and above code works as identity mapper job, which helps you write data in 1GB part file chunks.

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue